# dual sim android sdk

Tags: android, sim-card, dual-sim

Is there any way in sdk(default) that can handle dual sims? There are many number of android phones available in market which are dual sim. What i want is programmatically change the default sim. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use Java reflection to get dual SIM info [See here is demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/703851)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Android 5.1 [Multiple-Sim Support](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#multisim) has been officially added to the Android SDK!

You can access information about the current used sim through the [SubscriptionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html) class.

Comment: @JoséTomásTocino Thanks for asking! I've updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `SubscriptionInfo` class for achieving that, here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62910979/5351055) by me