# Android dual SIM card API

Tags: android, sim-card

There are several questions about accessing dual SIM features through the Android SDK, all of which are answered with brief statements that such features are unsupported in Android.

In spite of this, dual SIM phones do exist, and applications like [MultiSim](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.qianqin.multisim&hl=en) seem to be able to detect this in some kind of manufacturer-independent way.

So, beginning with that acknowledgement, let me try to ask some more pointed questions:

- Does "Android SDK does not support multiple SIM features" mean that these features do not exist, or that it is merely a bad idea to try to use them?
- Is there an Android content provider or an internal package (com.android...) that provides SIM card information? (TelephonyManager, as far as I can see in the docs and the code, has no mention of multiple SIM cards)
- Is there any report of any manufacturer exposing multiple SIM features to developers?
- If I were to look for undocumented functionality from a manufacturer, how would I go about that?

(By the way, the point of all of this is merely to implement this algorithm: send an SMS with SIM card 1; if delivery fails, switch to SIM card 2 and resend the message that way.)

Comment: @user1447002-Have u succeeded in building this app..?? Coz i suffer from same problems and have to provide a similar feature in my application..

Comment: No I haven't. I've seen postings from insiders at Google, Samsung, and Motorola to the effect that they are not making the code available.

Comment: @user1447002-Thanks man..but did u found any alternative to that..??

Comment: No, I didn't. I went as far as looking at the available activities and intents using some app (sorry, I forget the name), but there was nothing I could see.

Comment: Actually, I've just discovered that in my Samsung Galaxy Y Duos, whenever I send an SMS from the API it goes through the first sim card, even if I've switched the phone over to the second sim card. That suggests to me that there isn't actually an API; they've just hardwired the code to the first sim slot.

Comment: @user1447002-Ok..I got that one...I am having the same problem right now !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `MultiSim` library to get details from multi-sim devices.

Available info from each sim card: IMEI, IMSI, SIM Serial Number, SIM State, SIM operator code, SIM operator name, SIM country iso, network operator code, network operator name, network operator iso, network type, roaming status.

Just add the lines below in your app-level Gradle script:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.kirianov.multisim:multisim:2.0@aar'
}
```

Don't forget add required permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Use similar code in your code:

```
MultiSimTelephonyManager multiSimTelephonyManager = new MultiSimTelephonyManager(this);
// or
MultiSimTelephonyManager multiSimTelephonyManager = new MultiSimTelephonyManager(this, new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    updateInfo();
  }
});


public void updateInfo() {

  // for update UI
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      multiSimTelephonyManager.update();
      useInfo();
    }
  }

  // for update background information
  multiSimTelephonyManager.update();
  useInfo();
}

public void useInfo() {

  // get number of slots:
  if (multiSimTelephonyManager != null) {
     multiSimTelephonyManager.sizeSlots();
  }

  // get info from each slot:
  if (multiSimTelephonyManager != null) {
    for(int i = 0; i < multiSimTelephonyManager.sizeSlots(); i++) {
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).getImei();
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).getImsi();
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).getSimSerialNumber();
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).getSimState();
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).getSimOperator();
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).getSimOperatorName();
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).getSimCountryIso();
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).getNetworkOperator();
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).getNetworkOperatorName();
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).getNetworkCountryIso();
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).getNetworkType();
      multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).isNetworkRoaming();
    }
  }
}

// or for devices above android 6.0
MultiSimTelephonyManager multiSimTelephonyManager = new MultiSimTelephonyManager(MyActivity.this, broadcastReceiverChange);
```

Usage:

```
// get info about slot 'i' by methods:
multiSimTelephonyManager.getSlot(i).
```

Force update info:

```
// force update phone info (needed on devices above android 6.0 after confirm permissions request)
multiSimTelephonyManager.update();
```

Handle of permissions request (6.0+):

```
// in YourActivity for update info after confirm permissions request on  devices above android 6.0
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (multiSimTelephonyManager != null) {
        multiSimTelephonyManager.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this library open-source? I couldn't find it on the web and needed to know if it's still maintained.

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/UseHover/MultiSim, not sure it works on Android 10+ cause there are lots of restrictions on SubscriberId which apps can no longer get.

Comment: This library works with triple sim devices?

Comment: if don't support, there is any library that support implement a triple sim device, checking each chip info, deactivate and activate each SIM programmatically?

Answer (score 8):

there are 3 different categories ...

1. features supported and documented
2. Features available and un-documented
3. features unavailable

So the dual sim features are available but not documented and hence not officially supported.

Having said that it doesn't mean that it will not be usable , It just means that android(or for that matter google or even manufaturer) is not liable to support your apps functionality.

But it  might just work , for eg the contacts is a similar thing.

You might then ask up how would everyone know about the features if in case its not documented.. Hey android is open source .. go look into code and find it for yourself . Thats what I guess the multi sim developers did.

Comment: I have had a careful look through the source, to the extent that I was able (I mentioned that in my first post, but not very prominently). If anyone has done so and had better luck, I would be glad to hear about it.

Comment: You can use Java reflection to get dual SIM info. [See here is demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/703851)

Comment: @GauravShah, so anyway... how to send choose SIM 1 / 2 while sending the sms through the code?

Answer (score 5):

Android does not support multiple SIM features before API 22. But from Android 5.1 (API level 22) onwards, Android started supporting multiple SIMs.  More details on [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList%28%29)

Reference from this [Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996197/detect-the-status-of-two-sim-cards-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SubscriptionInfo` class to achieve it,

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        val mSubscriptionManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
        // val mSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(baseContext)
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val subscriptions = mSubscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList
        //loop through number of SIMS inserted
            for (subscriptionInfo in subscriptions) {
                //the number of this subscription if the calling app has been granted the READ_PHONE_NUMBERS permission, or an empty string otherwise
                Log.v("SIM", subscriptionInfo.number)
                //the ISO country code
                Log.v("SIM", subscriptionInfo.countryIso)
                //the name displayed to the user that identifies Subscription provider name
                Log.v("SIM", subscriptionInfo.carrierName.toString())
                //the name displayed to the user that identifies this subscription
                Log.v("SIM", subscriptionInfo.displayName.toString())
                //The MCC, as a string. This value may be null.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    Log.v("SIM", subscriptionInfo.mccString.toString())
                } else {
                    Log.v("SIM", subscriptionInfo.mcc.toString())
                }
                //The MNC, as a string. This value may be null.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    Log.v("SIM", subscriptionInfo.mncString.toString())
                } else {
                    Log.v("SIM", subscriptionInfo.mnc.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MultiSim library sources now are not available on VCS
It's sources is still available here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.kirianov.multisim/multisim
I have rewrote it on Kotlin for personal usage

```
class Slot {

    var imei: String? = null

    var imsi: String? = null

    var simState = -1

    val simStates = hashSetOf<Int>()

    var simSerialNumber: String? = null

    var simOperator: String? = null

    var simCountryIso: String? = null

    fun setSimState(state: Int?) {
        if (state == null) {
            simState = -1
            return
        }
        simState = state
    }

    private fun compare(slot: Slot?): Boolean {
        return if (slot != null) {
            imei == slot.imei && imsi == slot.imsi && simSerialNumber == slot.simSerialNumber
        } else false
    }

    fun indexIn(slots: List<Slot>?): Int {
        if (slots == null) {
            return -1
        }
        for (i in slots.indices) {
            if (compare(slots[i])) {
                return i
            }
        }
        return -1
    }

    fun containsIn(slots: List<Slot>?): Boolean {
        if (slots == null) {
            return false
        }
        for (slot in slots) {
            if (compare(slot)) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Slot(" +
            "imei=$imei, " +
            "imsi=$imsi, " +
            "simState=$simState, " +
            "simStates=$simStates, " +
            "simSerialNumber=$simSerialNumber, " +
            "simOperator=$simOperator, " +
            "simCountryIso=$simCountryIso" +
            ")"
    }
}
```

Also i remove native lib dependencies

```
import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.telephony.SubscriptionManager
import android.text.TextUtils
import domain.shadowss.extension.areGranted
import domain.shadowss.extension.isLollipopMR1Plus
import domain.shadowss.extension.isMarshmallowPlus
import domain.shadowss.extension.isOreoPlus
import domain.shadowss.model.Slot
import org.jetbrains.anko.telephonyManager
import timber.log.Timber
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier
import java.util.*

/**
 * https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.kirianov.multisim/multisim
 */
@Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")
class MultiSimManager(context: Context) {

    private val reference = WeakReference(context)

    val slots = arrayListOf<Slot>()
        @Synchronized get

    @Suppress("unused")
    val dualMcc: Pair<String?, String?>
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
        get() = reference.get()?.run {
            if (isLollipopMR1Plus()) {
                if (areGranted(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                    val subscriptionManager =
                        getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
                    val list = subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList
                    return list.getOrNull(0)?.mcc?.toString()
                        ?.padStart(3, '0') to list.getOrNull(1)?.mcc?.toString()
                        ?.padStart(3, '0')
                }
            }
            null to null
        } ?: null to null

    @Synchronized
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun updateData(): String? = reference.get()?.run {
        if (areGranted(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
            val error = try {
                var slotNumber = 0
                while (true) {
                    val slot = touchSlot(slotNumber)
                    if (slot == null) {
                        for (i in slotNumber until slots.size) {
                            slots.removeAt(i)
                        }
                        break
                    }
                    if (slot.containsIn(slots) && slot.indexIn(slots) < slotNumber) {
                        // protect from Alcatel infinity bug
                        break
                    }
                    slots.apply {
                        when {
                            size > slotNumber -> {
                                removeAt(slotNumber)
                                add(slotNumber, slot)
                            }
                            size == slotNumber -> add(slot)
                        }
                    }
                    slotNumber++
                }
                null
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                Timber.e(e)
                e.toString()
            }
            // below is my custom logic only which was found on practice
            slots.removeAll { it.imsi == null || it.simOperator?.trim()?.isEmpty() != false }
            val imsi = arrayListOf<String?>()
            slots.forEachReversedWithIndex { i, slot ->
                if (imsi.contains(slot.imsi)) {
                    slots.removeAt(i)
                } else {
                    imsi.add(slot.imsi)
                    slot.simStates.apply {
                        clear()
                        addAll(slots.filter { it.imsi == slot.imsi }.map { it.simState })
                    }
                }
            }
            error
        } else {
            slots.clear()
            null
        }
    }

    @Suppress("SpellCheckingInspection", "DEPRECATION")
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission", "HardwareIds")
    private fun touchSlot(slotNumber: Int): Slot? = reference.get()?.run {
        val slot = Slot()
        val telephonyManager = telephonyManager
        Timber.v("telephonyManager [$telephonyManager] ${telephonyManager.deviceId}")
        val subscriberIdIntValue = ArrayList<String>()
        val subscriberIdIntIndex = ArrayList<Int>()
        for (i in 0..99) {
            val subscriber = runMethodReflect(
                telephonyManager,
                "android.telephony.TelephonyManager",
                "getSubscriberId",
                arrayOf(i),
                null
            ) as? String
            if (subscriber != null && !subscriberIdIntValue.contains(subscriber)) {
                subscriberIdIntValue.add(subscriber)
                subscriberIdIntIndex.add(i)
            }
        }
        var subIdInt =
            if (subscriberIdIntIndex.size > slotNumber) subscriberIdIntIndex[slotNumber] else null
        if (subIdInt == null) {
            try {
                subIdInt = runMethodReflect(
                    telephonyManager,
                    "android.telephony.TelephonyManager",
                    "getSubId",
                    arrayOf(slotNumber),
                    null
                ).toString().toInt()
            } catch (ignored: Throwable) {
            }
        }
        Timber.v("subIdInt $subIdInt")
        val subscriberIdLongValue = ArrayList<String>()
        val subscriberIdLongIndex = ArrayList<Long>()
        for (i in 0L until 100L) {
            val subscriber = runMethodReflect(
                telephonyManager,
                "android.telephony.TelephonyManager",
                "getSubscriberId",
                arrayOf(i),
                null
            ) as? String
            runMethodReflect(
                telephonyManager,
                "android.telephony.TelephonyManagerSprd",
                "getSubInfoForSubscriber",
                arrayOf(i),
                null
            ) ?: continue
            if (subscriber != null && !subscriberIdLongValue.contains(subscriber)) {
                subscriberIdLongValue.add(subscriber)
                subscriberIdLongIndex.add(i)
            }
        }
        if (subscriberIdLongIndex.size <= 0) {
            for (i in 0L until 100L) {
                val subscriber = runMethodReflect(
                    telephonyManager,
                    "android.telephony.TelephonyManager",
                    "getSubscriberId",
                    arrayOf(i),
                    null
                ) as? String
                if (subscriber != null && !subscriberIdLongValue.contains(subscriber)) {
                    subscriberIdLongValue.add(subscriber)
                    subscriberIdLongIndex.add(i)
                }
            }
        }
        var subIdLong =
            if (subscriberIdLongIndex.size > slotNumber) subscriberIdLongIndex[slotNumber] else null
        if (subIdLong == null) {
            subIdLong = runMethodReflect(
                telephonyManager,
                "android.telephony.TelephonyManager",
                "getSubId",
                arrayOf(slotNumber),
                null
            ) as? Long
        }
        Timber.v("subIdLong $subIdLong")
        val listParamsSubs = ArrayList<Any?>()
        if (subIdInt != null && !listParamsSubs.contains(subIdInt)) {
            listParamsSubs.add(subIdInt)
        }
        if (subIdLong != null && !listParamsSubs.contains(subIdLong)) {
            listParamsSubs.add(subIdLong)
        }
        if (!listParamsSubs.contains(slotNumber)) {
            listParamsSubs.add(slotNumber)
        }
        val objectParamsSubs = listParamsSubs.toTypedArray()
        for (i in objectParamsSubs.indices) {
            Timber.v("SPAM PARAMS_SUBS [$i]=[${objectParamsSubs[i]}]")
        }
        val listParamsSlot = ArrayList<Any?>()
        if (!listParamsSlot.contains(slotNumber)) {
            listParamsSlot.add(slotNumber)
        }
        if (subIdInt != null && !listParamsSlot.contains(subIdInt)) {
            listParamsSlot.add(subIdInt)
        }
        if (subIdLong != null && !listParamsSlot.contains(subIdLong)) {
            listParamsSlot.add(subIdLong)
        }
        val objectParamsSlot = listParamsSlot.toTypedArray()
        for (i in objectParamsSlot.indices) {
            Timber.v("SPAM PARAMS_SLOT [$i]=[${objectParamsSlot[i]}]")
        }
        // firstly all Int params, then all Long params
        Timber.v("------------------------------------------")
        Timber.v("SLOT [$slotNumber]")
        if (isMarshmallowPlus()) {
            slot.imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId(slotNumber)
        }
        if (slot.imei == null) {
            slot.imei = iterateMethods("getDeviceId", objectParamsSlot) as? String
        }
        if (slot.imei == null) {
            slot.imei = runMethodReflect(
                null,
                "com.android.internal.telephony.Phone",
                null,
                null,
                "GEMINI_SIM_" + (slotNumber + 1)
            ) as? String
        }
        if (slot.imei == null) {
            slot.imei = runMethodReflect(
                getSystemService("phone" + (slotNumber + 1)),
                null,
                "getDeviceId",
                null,
                null
            ) as? String
        }
        Timber.v("IMEI [${slot.imei}]")
        if (slot.imei == null) {
            when (slotNumber) {
                0 -> {
                    slot.imei = if (isOreoPlus()) {
                        telephonyManager.imei
                    } else {
                        telephonyManager.deviceId
                    }
                    slot.imsi = telephonyManager.subscriberId
                    slot.simState = telephonyManager.simState
                    slot.simOperator = telephonyManager.simOperator
                    slot.simSerialNumber = telephonyManager.simSerialNumber
                    slot.simCountryIso = telephonyManager.simCountryIso
                    return slot
                }
            }
        }
        if (slot.imei == null) {
            return null
        }
        slot.setSimState(iterateMethods("getSimState", objectParamsSlot) as? Int)
        Timber.v("SIMSTATE [${slot.simState}]")
        slot.imsi = iterateMethods("getSubscriberId", objectParamsSubs) as? String
        Timber.v("IMSI [${slot.imsi}]")
        slot.simSerialNumber = iterateMethods("getSimSerialNumber", objectParamsSubs) as? String
        Timber.v("SIMSERIALNUMBER [${slot.simSerialNumber}]")
        slot.simOperator = iterateMethods("getSimOperator", objectParamsSubs) as? String
        Timber.v("SIMOPERATOR [${slot.simOperator}]")
        slot.simCountryIso = iterateMethods("getSimCountryIso", objectParamsSubs) as? String
        Timber.v("SIMCOUNTRYISO [${slot.simCountryIso}]")
        Timber.v("------------------------------------------")
        return slot
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private fun iterateMethods(methodName: String?, methodParams: Array<Any?>): Any? =
        reference.get()?.run {
            if (methodName == null || methodName.isEmpty()) {
                return null
            }
            val telephonyManager = telephonyManager
            val instanceMethods = ArrayList<Any?>()
            val multiSimTelephonyManagerExists = telephonyManager.toString()
                .startsWith("android.telephony.MultiSimTelephonyManager")
            for (methodParam in methodParams) {
                if (methodParam == null) {
                    continue
                }
                val objectMulti = if (multiSimTelephonyManagerExists) {
                    runMethodReflect(
                        null,
                        "android.telephony.MultiSimTelephonyManager",
                        "getDefault",
                        arrayOf(methodParam),
                        null
                    )
                } else {
                    telephonyManager
                }
                if (!instanceMethods.contains(objectMulti)) {
                    instanceMethods.add(objectMulti)
                }
            }
            if (!instanceMethods.contains(telephonyManager)) {
                instanceMethods.add(telephonyManager)
            }
            val telephonyManagerEx = runMethodReflect(
                null,
                "com.mediatek.telephony.TelephonyManagerEx",
                "getDefault",
                null,
                null
            )
            if (!instanceMethods.contains(telephonyManagerEx)) {
                instanceMethods.add(telephonyManagerEx)
            }
            val phoneMsim = getSystemService("phone_msim")
            if (!instanceMethods.contains(phoneMsim)) {
                instanceMethods.add(phoneMsim)
            }
            if (!instanceMethods.contains(null)) {
                instanceMethods.add(null)
            }
            var result: Any?
            for (methodSuffix in suffixes) {
                for (className in classNames) {
                    for (instanceMethod in instanceMethods) {
                        for (methodParam in methodParams) {
                            if (methodParam == null) {
                                continue
                            }
                            result = runMethodReflect(
                                instanceMethod,
                                className,
                                methodName + methodSuffix,
                                if (multiSimTelephonyManagerExists) null else arrayOf(methodParam),
                                null
                            )
                            if (result != null) {
                                return result
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null
        }

    private fun runMethodReflect(
        instanceInvoke: Any?,
        classInvokeName: String?,
        methodName: String?,
        methodParams: Array<Any>?,
        field: String?
    ): Any? {
        var result: Any? = null
        try {
            val classInvoke = when {
                classInvokeName != null -> Class.forName(classInvokeName)
                instanceInvoke != null -> instanceInvoke.javaClass
                else -> return null
            }
            if (field != null) {
                val fieldReflect = classInvoke.getField(field)
                val accessible = fieldReflect.isAccessible
                fieldReflect.isAccessible = true
                result = fieldReflect.get(null).toString()
                fieldReflect.isAccessible = accessible
            } else {
                var classesParams: Array<Class<*>?>? = null
                if (methodParams != null) {
                    classesParams = arrayOfNulls(methodParams.size)
                    for (i in methodParams.indices) {
                        classesParams[i] = when {
                            methodParams[i] is Int -> Int::class.javaPrimitiveType
                            methodParams[i] is Long -> Long::class.javaPrimitiveType
                            methodParams[i] is Boolean -> Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType
                            else -> methodParams[i].javaClass
                        }
                    }
                }
                val method = if (classesParams != null) {
                    classInvoke.getDeclaredMethod(methodName.toString(), *classesParams)
                } else {
                    classInvoke.getDeclaredMethod(methodName.toString())
                }
                val accessible = method.isAccessible
                method.isAccessible = true
                result = if (methodParams != null) {
                    method.invoke(instanceInvoke ?: classInvoke, *methodParams)
                } else {
                    method.invoke(instanceInvoke ?: classInvoke)
                }
                method.isAccessible = accessible
            }
        } catch (ignored: Throwable) {
        }
        return result
    }

    @Suppress("unused")
    val allMethodsAndFields: String
        get() = """
            Default: ${reference.get()?.telephonyManager}${'\n'}
            ${printAllMethodsAndFields("android.telephony.TelephonyManager")}
            ${printAllMethodsAndFields("android.telephony.MultiSimTelephonyManager")}
            ${printAllMethodsAndFields("android.telephony.MSimTelephonyManager")}
            ${printAllMethodsAndFields("com.mediatek.telephony.TelephonyManager")}
            ${printAllMethodsAndFields("com.mediatek.telephony.TelephonyManagerEx")}
            ${printAllMethodsAndFields("com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony")}
        """.trimIndent()

    private fun printAllMethodsAndFields(className: String): String {
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        builder.append("========== $className\n")
        try {
            val cls = Class.forName(className)
            for (method in cls.methods) {
                val params = method.parameterTypes.map { it.name }
                builder.append(
                    "M: ${method.name} [${params.size}](${TextUtils.join(
                        ",",
                        params
                    )}) -> ${method.returnType} ${if (Modifier.isStatic(method.modifiers)) "(static)" else ""}\n"
                )
            }
            for (field in cls.fields) {
                builder.append("F: ${field.name} ${field.type}\n")
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            builder.append("E: $e\n")
        }
        return builder.toString()
    }

    companion object {

        private val classNames = arrayOf(
            null,
            "android.telephony.TelephonyManager",
            "android.telephony.MSimTelephonyManager",
            "android.telephony.MultiSimTelephonyManager",
            "com.mediatek.telephony.TelephonyManagerEx",
            "com.android.internal.telephony.Phone",
            "com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneFactory"
        )

        private val suffixes = arrayOf(
            "",
            "Gemini",
            "Ext",
            "Ds",
            "ForSubscription",
            "ForPhone"
        )
    }
}
```

May be it wiil be helpful for somebody

Answer (score -2):

```
 <receiver
     android:name=".SimChangedReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:process=":remote" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

SimChangedReceiver class

public class SimChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED")) {
        Log.d("SimChangedReceiver", "--> SIM state changed <--");   

      //            do code  whatever u want to apply action                //

    }
   }
}
```

this is work for dual sim also , and you don't need to call this receiver because it will run remotely

Comment: How did you pass the filter?