# Android dual sim support

Tags: android

Does android natively support the dual sim feature?
Or is android extended by manufacturers to do so?

In particular, I'd like to make a sim switching app just like the ones in Samsung phones.

Also can anyone tell me in which system apk are the status bar and notifications located?
I'm trying to reverse engineer the Samsung sim switching feature.

Thanks.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305407/android-dual-sim-card-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, dual SIM is not supported in Android out of the box. It is a custom modification by manufacturers, and there is no public API to control it.

The status bar and notifications are location in SystemUI.apk, but I doubt you'll be able to get much out of them. Any APIs used in their are unlikely to be available to third parties.

Comment: Actually, status bar and notification pull-down are in SystemUI.apk which can be decompiled to smali code. Of course, it's a system package so it may or may not be available depending on whether you have root.