# Detect target phone number on incoming call

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have an Android phone with 2 SIM card and I want to detect the target of the incoming call — is it for SIM 1 or for SIM 2. Is it possible to get the target number from call info?

Answer (score 1):

Your question dosent have answers in the documentations...

But I found out some links that may help you out:

1. [Checking for dual sim.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/2219600)
2. [Question regarding ui.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11305495/2219600)

Comment: Thanks, the information at the first URL is very useful.

Comment: @amalBit: Please don't post links in your answer as links can be stale or die. Please summarise your answer with the info provided in the links. Thanks.