# How to get 2nd sim phone no of device programmatically

Tags: java, android

I want get user phone number programmatically to fill user phone number field in my application. I want to get second sim phone number for dual sim phone. But i can only fetch first sim phone number,i follow this link for fetch phone number.
[Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

```
 TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

add this into manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim/17499889#17499889

Comment: through this link can get imei number,but i want to get phone number @kgandroid

Comment: hey read this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/2219600 and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618651/detect-target-phone-number-on-incoming-call/21448605#21448605)
its very infomative