# Android Dual-SIM API support

Tags: android, dual-sim

I was looking for Android Dual-SIM API for Android, but more or less I found nothing. As far as I understand, there is no public API from Google/Android, only specific implementation of each manufacturer. Therefore is very hard to implement application supporting Dual-SIM (or more SIM) devices.

If I am not wrong about it in this time (17.02.2015), is there anything we (developers) can do to request/force Google to implement this?

I would like to "guide" all developers to same place (if there is one) to increase our power.

Thank you for any feedback.

[UPDATE: 10.03.2015]

**Android support DUAL-SIM/MULTIPLE SIM cards in API since ANDROID 5.1.**

***Whether you want to share your phone with a family member or better manage your mobile costs, Android Lollipop 5.1 now lets you use more than one SIM card on a device with multiple SIM slots.***

[Read more here](http://new%20features%20like%20support%20for%20multiple%20SIM%20cards) and [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html).

Comment: Certainly we dont have authority to force google..I too believe it should not be part of android API and should only be provided by manufacturers.

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ on what grounds do you believe it should be up to the manufacturers? That would mean any application designed to work with dual SIMs would need to implement the propitiatory APIs of every individual manufacturer! 5.1 implements a few APIs but nothing very useful like switching SIM card status etc.

Comment: Try use MultiSim library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41544422/1665964

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, Google has *never* openly discussed their rationale for not supporting multi-SIM devices out-of-the-box, even though manufacturers are quite clearly gung-ho about it. None of Google's `Nexus` devices has had this feature, so obviously they do not advocate multi-SIM devices, whatever their reason.

I suspect it has something to do with security, and also with Google's perception of a smartphone being an abstraction of an ***individual***, and all data being connected with a single phone SIM account, and thus representing that ***individual***. Or maybe I'm crazy.

The official Google review branch for this feature is [here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/79991/). And the only relevant post on SO for working around this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim).

**UPDATE:**

Both [**Multiple SIM Card Support**](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#multisim) and [**True multi-user support**](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers) are available.

Comment: Hi, I thank you for your answer, but it seems to be crazy. Google has own plans, I understand to this, but still he should listen somewhere, I just don´t know where. I know I can´t really force them, I just want to see them us asking for this and together I believe we have chance. 
Thank you for pointing me to workaround, it could help me solve the problem, not for all devices, but for some.

Comment: The evolution of Java takes place through the [Java Community Process](https://www.jcp.org/en/home/index) and [Java Specification Requests](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/all). I don't believe Android has the equivalent of this. Although it is "open source" in a sense, Big Brother has the last say in determining the final shape of the OS.