# Android 5.1 switch dual-sim radios on and off

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, dual-sim

Android 5.1 now has official support for Dual Sim phones, [however there's not much currently available in the officially documented APIs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#multisim). Does anybody know how, with a rooted phone, an app can switch either SIM1 or SIM 2 On and Off?

Answer (score 0):

From the offical documentation mentioned the class `SubscriptionManager`,I just found something that could be switched:

DefaultVoice:

```
/** @hide */
    public void setDefaultVoiceSubId(int subId) {
        if (VDBG) logd("setDefaultVoiceSubId sub id = " + subId);
        try {
            ISub iSub = ISub.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("isub"));
            if (iSub != null) {
                iSub.setDefaultVoiceSubId(subId);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            // ignore it
        }
    }
```

DefaultSms:

```
/** @hide */
    public void setDefaultSmsSubId(int subId) {
        if (VDBG) logd("setDefaultSmsSubId sub id = " + subId);
        try {
            ISub iSub = ISub.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("isub"));
            if (iSub != null) {
                iSub.setDefaultSmsSubId(subId);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            // ignore it
        }
    }
```

DefaultData:

```
 /** @hide */
    public void setDefaultDataSubId(int subId) {
        if (VDBG) logd("setDataSubscription sub id = " + subId);
        try {
            ISub iSub = ISub.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("isub"));
            if (iSub != null) {
                iSub.setDefaultDataSubId(subId);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            // ignore it
        }
    }
```

But as you see,most of the methods of the class is `@hide`,that means it's not suitable to be public in the current version(Android 5.1.1/API Level 22).But you can also call them:
https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/using-com-android-internal-part-5-summary-and-example/

And also some information for you from this:

[Android dual SIM card API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305407/android-dual-sim-card-api)

Comment: These methods relate to switching default SIMs for actions, they don't enable me to turn a SIM on or off