# How to know data usage of mobile for specific sim slot

Tags: android, dual-sim

I am trying to find data usage by specific sim slot. For this I am using  TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() method but it gives total usage of both the sim in dual sim device. I want particular data usage of individual sim. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305407/android-dual-sim-card-api) and its answers?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

**Just a hint:** You could do something like upon sim slot data active event 
TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag(identifier_tag);

and

```
if(TrafficStats.getThreadStatsTag() == SIM1_SLOT){
     int usedBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() 
}else{
    // Sim2 slot
    int usedBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() 
}
```

Comment: always returns -1 for both first slot as well as for second slot.