# MultiSim library UnsatisfiedLinkError: findLibrary returned null

Tags: java, android

I'm using a third-party library to detect Multiple sims for both older versions of android and newer versions found from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41544422/1860982 by @Tapa Save But on adding the library to my dependencies and trying to run it throws an exception that it cannot find library.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.kirianov.multisim:multisim:1.0'
}
```

It just crashes and shows me this error

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load multisimlib from loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.sampleapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.sampleapp-2,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned
>   null

So i checked many sources on stackoverflow related to this issue, but none helped yet.

Comment: Please try use: compile 'com.kirianov.multisim:multisim:2.0@aar'

Comment: Still not work on android above 6.0 (run time permissions request), but I work on this issue

Comment: @TapaSave Thanks, But i got this error while trying to sync Error:(23, 13) Failed to resolve: com.kirianov.multisim:multisim:2.0

Comment: you use '@aar' suffix?

Comment: @TapaSave Yea, i used this exactly compile 'com.kirianov.multisim:multisim:2.0@aar'

Comment: Please try again, now it is available from jcenter

Comment: @TapaSave thanks, I tried it now & it gave the good results. I got output on my console like this : "I/MultiSim++: SLOT  [0]". Which was obviously printing from your class as using MultiSim++ as your String TAG. But your sample implementation did not output anything using this "multiSimTelephonyManager.sizeSlots()"; It was returning 0; I am referring you your implementation as you stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41544422/1860982

Comment: I update snippet in link above, you need run 'multiSimTelephonyManager.update();' and create 'BroadcastReceiver' for get new informations when device state changed or multiSimTelephonyManager launched firstly.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try adding multidex and adding mavenCentral() to project gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
        dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

    }
}
```

to add multidex follow https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html