# How to read dual sim device both sim contact in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, dual-sim

To read sim contact we use below URi

```
    Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn/");
    ContentResolver mContentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = mContentResolver.query(simUri, null, null, null, null);
```

By using this uri i only get my master sim contact not both sim contact, according to my requirement i have to read only sim contact. using above code i only read one sim contact. help me in find out solution that how can i read both sim contact. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also tried it once. After so many research I found the following link,

[dual sim android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382971/dual-sim-android-sdk?rq=1)

[Dual SIM card Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android)

To handle two sims, one need to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you refer me please official doc for this...i looking for official ans.

Comment: sry but i looking for an official ans.

Comment: I am looking for it. Wait

Comment: Hi Lokesh, as far as official website my search is still going. I found this link http://www.wenda.io/questions/362062/detect-the-status-of-two-sim-cards-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone.html It may help.

Comment: suppose i have to create contact programtically in sim1 and sim2 then can you please tell me what Sim URI we will Use thanx . @Pihu